# Can I use "is_expected" here?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have the following spec:

```
describe 'blah blah blah' do
  it 'yadda yadda yadda' do
    expect(Foo).not_to receive(:bar)
    subject
  end
end
```

To be clear, the test passes if `Foo.bar` is not called.

I'm curious, can `it` be turned into a one-liner, using the `is_expected` syntax?

i.e.

```
describe 'blah blah blah' do
  it { is_expected.to... }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `after`

```
after { subject }
it { expect(Foo).not_to receive(:bar) }
```

Comment: Thank you but I meant: can it be turned into a one-liner using the is_expected syntax, so I don't have to call subject?

Comment: I believe, that it is impossible in this case. You can do something like this, if your `#bar` changing something. If that true, you can do something like this: `it { expect  { subject }.to change { Foo.bars_count }.by(1) }`

Answer (score 0):

You can call `subject` in a [around(:each)](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/hooks/around-hooks) block.

```
describe 'blah blah blah' do
  around(:each) { |example| subject; example.run }
  it { is_expected not_to receive :bar }
end
```

This isn't really a one-liner, but the `around(:each)` is run for each example in the group (the `describe` in this case) so it can save repetition if you have multiple examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
describe 'blah blah blah' do
  before { expect(Foo).not_to receive(:bar) }
  it { is_expected }
end
```

I've done it a few times and some of my colleagues have found this style to be obscure